# How to customize expo-permissions "alert" demands on React-Native?

Tags: react-native, permissions, expo, customization

I am using **react-native** & **expo-permissions** to geolocalize a user.

```
Permissions.askAsync(Permissions.LOCATION);
```

is displaying an alert with this message to allow or deny:

> "Blank Template needs permissions for coarse location.(...) Allow
>   Blank Template to use your location?"

How can I change this message? Replacing Blank Template by my App name for example...
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to customize the `app.json` that comes from Expo:

```
{
  "expo": {
    "name": "Blank Template",
    "...": "..."
   }
}
```

Note that on Android, you cannot change the message, only your App Name. You can show a popup before that explains why you need the permissions.